# Unit testing Monorail's RenderText method

Tags: unit-testing, moq, castle-monorail

I'm doing some maintenance on an older web application written in Monorail v1.0.3.  I want to unit test an action that uses RenderText().  How do I extract the content in my test?  Reading from controller.Response.OutputStream doesn't work, since the response stream is either not setup properly in PrepareController(), or is closed in RenderText().

**Example Action**

```
public DeleteFoo( int id )
{
    var success= false;
    var foo = Service.Get<Foo>( id );
    if( foo != null && CurrentUser.IsInRole( "CanDeleteFoo" ) )
    {
        Service.Delete<Foo>( id );
        success = true;
    }

    CancelView();
    RenderText( "{ success: " + success + " }" );
}
```

**Example Test (using Moq)**

```
[Test]
public void DeleteFoo()
{
    var controller = new FooController ();
    PrepareController ( controller );

    var foo = new Foo { Id = 123 };

    var mockService = new Mock < Service > ();
    mockService.Setup ( s => s.Get<Foo> ( foo.Id ) ).Returns ( foo );
    controller.Service = mockService.Object;

    controller.DeleteTicket ( foo.Id );

    mockService.Verify ( s => s.Delete<Foo> ( foo.Id ) );
    Assert.AreEqual ( "{success:true}", GetResponse ( Response ) );
}

// response.OutputStream.Seek throws an "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream." exception
private static string GetResponse( IResponse response )
{
    response.OutputStream.Seek ( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
    var buffer = new byte[response.OutputStream.Length];
    response.OutputStream.Read ( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString ( buffer );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `BaseControllerTest.BuildResponse()` and provide your mock of `IMockResponse` built with Moq.